# Java screen capture using robot class

Tags: java, windows-7

I use robot class to take capture and save the file on C: drive in xp. It works fine, but when used with windows 7 i get exception saying access denied, accessing file using native method.

Is it because i am using C: drive and not the system tmp directory or something else?
I do not have windows 7 to test it here, thats why asking.

Code is something like this:

```
Dimension screenSize;
Rectangle screenRectangle;
BufferedImage image;

for (int i=0; i<j; i++){
    img[i] = "C:\\"+(i+1)+".jpg"; //e.g 1.jpg saved in C: drive on 1st itr.
    screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
    image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(img[i]));
}
```

Comment: Please read over http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

Write permissions for the root directory are by default off in Windows 7.  You can change your code to

`img[i] = (i+1)+".jpg";`

in order to write your screen-capture images to the same directory from which you launched the jvm.